# Not able to Send Email for Person Account

Tags: apex, class, error, error-messages, person-accounts

I am facing one issue and i don't know what is it, i am going to send and Email template to the Contact via Send Email Method but it will not working for Person Account...It is working for Business Account Perfectly.

Can anybody knows this...?

[image]

Here is My Method :

```
  // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        // Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID
        PageReference quotePdf = Page.PrintQuote;
        quotePdf.getParameters().put('id', quote.Id);
        quotePdf.setRedirect(true);

        // Take the PDF content
        Blob b= Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : quotePdf.getContent();
      /*  Blob  b;
       if (Test.IsRunningTest()){
            b=Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');
           }
       else{
            b = quotePdf.getcontentAsPdf();
        }*/


        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName( quote.Name + '.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b);
        fileAttachments.add(efa);

        Attachment att = new Attachment();
        att.body = b;
        att.Name = quote.Name + '.pdf';
        attList.add(att);

        for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :oppty.Id]) {
            // Add to attachment file list
            Messaging.Emailfileattachment opptyAttach = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            opptyAttach.setFileName(a.Name);
            opptyAttach.setBody(a.Body);
            fileAttachments.add(opptyAttach);

            Attachment att1 = new Attachment();
            att1.body = a.Body;
            att1.Name = a.Name;
            attList.add(att1);
        }
        email.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);

        //create dummy contact
        contact con = new contact();
        con.lastname = 'test con';
        con.Email = 'dummy@organization.com';
        con.accountid = quote.Opportunity__r.AccountId;
        insert con;

        email.setTemplateId( selectedTemplateId );
        email.setPlainTextBody(' ');
        email.setWhatId(oppty.id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(con.id);
        email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{quote.Opportunity__r.Account.Email__c});
        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        if (r.get(0).isSuccess()) {
            //delete con;

            Task conTask = [Select Id, Subject, Description, Status, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhoId =: con.Id];
            conTask.WhoId = null;
            update conTask;

            if(!attList.isEmpty()){
                for(Attachment attOne : attList){
                    attOne.ParentId = conTask.Id;
                }

                insert attList;
            }
            delete con;
        }

    } catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug('@@ex : '+ ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
```

Here is the Debug Log :

```
17:59:45.365 (365289954)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:59:45.374 (374242038)|DML_END|[80]
17:59:45.374 (374345877)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Can not select a person account
17:59:45.374 (374455141)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[80]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can not select a person account: [AccountId]
17:59:45.374 (374871091)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[80]|Bytes:131
17:59:45.374 (374911869)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[106]|ex|Exception|true|false
17:59:45.375 (375008887)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[106]|ex|"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can not select a person account: [AccountId]"|0xb720d38
17:59:45.375 (375020072)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[106]
17:59:45.375 (375023602)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[107]
17:59:45.375 (375028953)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[107]|Bytes:7
17:59:45.375 (375092756)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[107]|Bytes:127
17:59:45.375 (375115362)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[107]|Bytes:134
17:59:45.375 (375137936)|USER_DEBUG|[107]|DEBUG|@@ex : Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can not select a person account: [AccountId]
17:59:45.375 (375148335)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[109]
17:59:45.375 (375537174)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SendEmailWithAttachmentsController invoke(sendEmail)
17:59:45.376 (376134040)|VF_APEX_CALL|j_id30|{!sendEmail}|PageReference: none
17:59:45.380 (380563876)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
17:59:45.380 (380574167)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:59:45.380 (380589584)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[-1]|this.conSeverity|"ERROR"|0x59d07d55
17:59:45.380 (380706672)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:59:45.380 (380713611)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:59:45.380 (380724950)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[-1]|this.conStrength|2|0x59d07d55
17:59:45.388 (388891596)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
17:59:45.388 (388901003)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:59:45.388 (388919195)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[-1]|this.conSeverity|"ERROR"|0x59d07d55
17:59:45.389 (389015758)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
17:59:45.389 (389021441)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
17:59:45.389 (389031672)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[-1]|this.conStrength|2|0x59d07d55
```

Comment: It there a validation rule / lookup filter  on the Account Name lookup field?

Comment: No Eric. No Validation Rule / lookup filter on the Account Name

Comment: @Eric , Here is edited question. i added my debug log with the errors.please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your error is here:

```
con.accountid = quote.Opportunity__r.AccountId;
insert con;
```

When creating a contact you cannot set the account ID to a person account.

try setting the `email.setTargetObjectId(quote.Opportunity__r.AccountId)`

Comment: You mean instead of email.setTargetObjectId(con.id) i have to try that you given..??

Comment: Yes. You can't create your dummy contact since the account is a person account

Comment: Ooopppss !! I am still getting the same error for Person Account.

Comment: You can't be getting the same error if you are not trying to create the dummy contact

Comment: Ok. let me comment that code of creation for dummy contact and let you know..

Comment: @Nihar - great. Now don;t forget to add checks in there to ensure that the Opportunity__r.AccountID is actually as person account and if not then you can create the dummy contact

Comment: Ohh Yes. keep this thing in my mind...Thanks a lot for your time